# What is the best situation to set a "Too Broad" flag into questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, needs-more-focus

Sometimes I have a doubt about setting the "Too Broad" flag into questions in Stack Overflow, and consequently I'm caught think about if I'm doing it wrong or not.

I think if it's incomplete I can ask about more details or maybe set "Unclear" according to the content and, after the post improvement by it's owner, I help.

What you think about it? I have not so much time here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag descriptions should be fairly clear, as written.

- **A question is "too broad"** if it cannot reasonably be answered by a single answer, of the length expected for Stack Overflow. In other words, if you can't imagine yourself sitting down and writing a succinct, 3–4 paragraph answer that completely and accurately answers the question, it is almost certainly "too broad".

  (Either that, or you are not sufficiently knowledgeable about the topic to answer it without writing a rambling answer filled with irrelevant noise. But in that case, either you should not be flagging questions about that topic, or your flag will be ignored because there will not be enough people who agree with you.)

  Questions are commonly closed as "too broad" when answering them would require that an entire book or tutorial be written. Another reason that questions are commonly closed as "too broad" is when they ask more than one question. The rule is one question per question!
- **A question is "unclear"** if it is unclear what the person is asking and/or what type of answer they are expecting. A question is also unclear if insufficient information is provided in the question to be able to understand the problem. This is intentionally a broad brush; lots of poorly asked questions with insufficient detail fall under this flag/close reason. Use your best judgment.

I don't know what you mean by "I help". If you mean that you post an answer anyway, then you should stop doing this. You can "help" by leaving comments suggesting improvements that the person can make to the post, and you can "help" by flagging problematic posts. But it is not helping anyone to try to answer questions that are unclear, too broad, or otherwise problematic.

Comment: Thanks @Cody Gary for the explanation! The "I help" is about answer the question or commenting.

Answer (score 1):

As the description of the flag says:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

One must use it if:

1. There are too many possible (obviously correct) answers for that question.
2. Answers are too long and cover a wide range, like more than one topic. For instance, just like a *Class* in OOP which is expected to represent just one thing, and not span across similar things.

Comment: Thanks @CinCout for the answer!